# The regex pattern is not matching the filenames inside the directories

Tags: java, regex

I develop this code in order to parse images filename inside a directory, there is two types of files, photos and images, so each had a different filename pattern, so I came out with this approach, looking inside the folders and get a list of all the images (photos and images) an then match the right pattern to get the values.

The problem is for some reason the regex patterns are not matching the filenames, I already check the syntax and the pattern using this link https://regex101.com/r/cvuEfR/3 to validate them.

So I'm think the problem is somewhere else, but I don't get it.

The file structure and the files look like this

```
resource_files
  |_Photos
    |_1
      RD1500-0001-1-P.JPG
      RD1500-0001-2-P.JPG
    |_2
      RD1500-0002-1-P.JPG
      RD1500-0002-2-P.JPG
  |_Images
    |_1
      |_extL       
        R0001A+01.01B+01-extL.JPG
        R0001A+01.10B+82-extL.JPG
    |_1
      |_extR       
        R0002A+10.10B+23-extL.JPG
        R0002A+01.10B+06-extL.JPG
```

I'm parsing the values for the photos as follows

```
RD1500-0001-1-P.JPG
1500
0001
1
P
```

and for the images:

```
R0002A+10.10B+23-extL.JPG
0002
10.10
23
extL
```

```java
public class ImageNameParser implements IImageNameProcessor {

    private static final String PHOTO_PATTERN="([A-Za-z0-9]+)-(\\d\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d)-([A-Za-z]+)";
    private Pattern photoPattern = Pattern.compile(PHOTO_PATTERN);

    private static final String IMAGE_PATTERN="([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\\d\\d\\d\\d)([A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\+](\\d\\d.\\d\\d)([A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\+](\\d\\d)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)";
    private Pattern imagePattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);

    private ImageHierarchy extractType1Info(File imageFile,String tag,String group) throws Exception {

        if (imageFile!=null && imageFile.isFile()) {
            Matcher m = imagePattern.matcher(imageFile.getName());
            if (m.find()) {

                /*    m.group(1) - 
                      m.group(2) - SubGroup
                          m.group(3) - 
                      m.group(4) - ValueA
                      m.group(5) -                    
                                      m.group(6) - ValueB
                      m.group(7) - SubType  
                 */
                ImageHierarchy imageData = new ImageHierarchy(imageFile.getName(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), m.group(2), tag, group);
                imageData.addImageParameters(m.group(4), m.group(6),m.group(7), null, null);
                return imageData;

            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ImageHierarchy extractType2Info(File imageFile,String tag,String group) {

        if (imageFile!=null && imageFile.isFile()) {

            Matcher patternMatcher = photoPattern.matcher(imageFile.getName());

            if (patternMatcher.find()) {
                /*
                     patternMatcher.group(1) - Group
                     patternMatcher.group(2) - SubGroup
                     patternMatcher.group(3) - SequenceNumber
                     patternMatcher.group(4) - PhotoAtribute
                 */

                ImageHierarchy imageData = new ImageHierarchy(imageFile.getName(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), patternMatcher.group(2), tag, patternMatcher.group(1));
                imageData.addImageParameters(null, null,null, patternMatcher.group(3), patternMatcher.group(4));
                return imageData;
            } 
        } 
        return null;
    }

    private File[] getFiles(File folder ,String group, String tag){

        ArrayList<File> fileList= new ArrayList<File>();

        if(folder!=null)
        {
            ArrayList<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>();
            directories.add(folder);

            while(!directories.isEmpty() && (folder = directories.remove(0))!=null) {
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                if(listOfFiles!=null)
                {
                    for ( File file : listOfFiles) {
                        if(file.isFile()){

                            if((group!=null && file.getName().contains(group)) || (tag!=null && file.getName().contains(tag))){
                                System.out.println(file.getName());
                                fileList.add(file);
                            }

                        } else if(file.isDirectory()){
                            directories.add(file);                   
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return fileList.toArray(new File[]{});

    }

    public ProcessedImages process(File folder ,String group,String tag) throws Exception{

        ImageHierarchy imageInfo = null;

        ProcessedImages collection = new ProcessedImages();
        File[] imageFiles = getFiles(folder, group, tag);
        for (File imageFile : imageFiles) {
            imageInfo = extractType1Info(imageFile, tag, group);
            if(imageInfo!=null)
            {
                collection.AddImage(imageInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                imageInfo = extractType2Info(imageFile,tag, group);
                if(imageInfo!=null)
                {
                    collection.AddImage(imageInfo);
                }
            }

        }
        return collection;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe you might be trying to write some expression with optionals, such as:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,2}(\d{4})[A-Z]?([+-]\d{2}\.?\d{2})[A-Z]?([+-][0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)
```

or maybe not, I'm not so sure.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^[A-Za-z]{1,2}(\\d{4})[A-Z]?([+-]\\d{2}\\.?\\d{2})[A-Z]?([+-][0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)";
        final String string = "A0001L+23.20K+01-Red.JPG\n"
             + "R0002A+10.10B+23-extL.JPG\n"
             + "RD1500-0001-1-P.JPG";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: A0001L+23.20K+01-Red
Group 1: 0001
Group 2: +23.20
Group 3: +01
Group 4: Red
Full match: R0002A+10.10B+23-extL
Group 1: 0002
Group 2: +10.10
Group 3: +23
Group 4: extL
Full match: RD1500-0001-1-P
Group 1: 1500
Group 2: -0001
Group 3: -1
Group 4: P
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XOdKzv/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XOdKzv/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---